# ECR login fails in gitlab runner

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to deploy ECS with task definition and I'm using ECR to store my docker image in was. When I try to login ECR in GitLab CI/CD with shared runner. I'm getting errors.

```
image: docker:19.03.11

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  REPOSITORY_URL: <REPOSITORY_URL>
  TASK_DEFINITION_NAME: <Task_Definition>
  CLUSTER_NAME: <CLUSTER_NAME>
  SERVICE_NAME: <SERVICE_NAME>

before_script:
  - apk add --no-cache curl jq python py-pip
  - pip install awscli
  - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  - aws configure set region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
  - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region "${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}")
  - IMAGE_TAG="$(echo $CI_COMMIT_SHA | head -c 8)"

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Building image..."
    - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URL:latest .
    - echo "Tagging image..."
    - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URL:latest $REPOSITORY_URL:$IMAGE_TAG
    - echo "Pushing image..."
    - docker push $REPOSITORY_URL:latest
    - docker push $REPOSITORY_URL:$IMAGE_TAG
```

Error details:
[image]

Comment: Did you change the `/root/.docker/config.json` on GitLab runner?

Comment: Yes. I tried that too

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches that you can take to access a private registry. Both require setting the CI/CD variable DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG with appropriate authentication information.

Per-job: To configure one job to access a private registry, add DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG as a CI/CD variable.
Per-runner: To configure a runner so all its jobs can access a private registry, add DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG as an environment variable in the runner’s configuration.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#access-an-image-from-a-private-container-registry

Comment: Getting same error - error saving credentials

Answer (score 0):

I see the following issues in your config:

- `docker login` is missing
- without `DOCKER_HOST` docker:dind will not work

Please try to follow this tutorial - [link](https://medium.com/devops-with-valentine/gitlab-ci-build-push-docker-image-to-aws-ecr-elastic-container-registry-b63b91a58728), youtube video about the mentioned tutorial is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jg9sUceyGaQ).